# Loop to remove characters from string one by one

Tags: java

Hello I´d like to know a way to "remove" the characters of a string and print it. For example:
So far I was able to do the oposite:

```
    String str = "SUNDAY";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) 
    {
        sb.append(c);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

STRING = "SUNDAY"

SUNDAY

SUNDA

SUND

SUN

SU

S

Comment: Use `str.substring(0, n)`; or `sb = new StringBuilder(str)` and `sb.delete`.

Comment: complementing/alternative to @AndyTurner comment, use `sb = new StringBuilder(str)` and `sb.setLength(--length)`

Answer (score 1):

This might do it for you:

```
String s = "SUNDAY";
int j = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++, j--) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, j));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a `StringBuilder` to print sub string of your String.

You have to have a loop which will start at the loop counter at the length of the string and end at the counter is at 1 the counter should decrements at each loop.
Use the counter as the as the end index in [String.substring(beginindex,endindex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```java
String str = "SUNDAY";
for (int i = str.length(); i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit tricky `IntStream` version:

```
IntStream.range(0, s.length()).map(i -> s.length() - i).mapToObj(i -> s.substring(0, i)).forEach(System.out::println);
```